# babel-node is not recognized as internal or external command - Babel 7

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, babeljs, babel-node

I'm using babel v7.6.x and have set up the following.

package.json

```
 "scripts": {
    "dev": "nodemon --exec babel-node bin/index.js",
    "start": "babel-node bin/index.js",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
...
"devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.6.4",
    "@babel/node": "^7.6.3",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.6.3",
    "nodemon": "^1.19.4"
  }
```

.babelrc

```
{
    "presets":[
        "@babel/preset-env"
    ]
}
```

yet i am still getting :

```
'babel-node' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

It used to be working but since doing a recent npm install to get updated versions it has failed to start up successfully.

my node version is 10.15.2
npm version is 6.12.0

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove package directory:

```sh
rm -rf node_modules
```

Install again:

```sh
yarn
```

or

```
npm install
```

Check there is no errors

Check enough free space available

Check existence of files:

- `node_modules/.bin/babel-node`
- `node_modules/.bin/babel-node.cmd` - windows only
- `node_modules/@babel/node/bin/babel-node.js`

Comment: only this "node_modules/@babel/node/bin/babel-node.js" is not available in my node_modules, rest of the two files under .bin i could able to see. what we can do now ? is that any way to install this file alone ?

Comment: Have you installed "@babel/node" package as in question snippet of package.json demonstrated. Different versions may has different path (and amount of tools).

Answer (score 0):

I have also run into the same problem. but found the problem might have been with the plugin versions i was using.

[Check out this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65827453/nodemon-babel-node-not-recognized-as-internal-or-external-command/65827691?noredirect=1#comment116409811_65827691)