# [NODEMON]- babel-node not recognized as internal or external command

Tags: javascript, node.js, babeljs, nodemon, babel-node

I am trying to setup a simple express server. I am using nodemon to start my development server But my app keeps crashing because it does not recognize the "babel-node" command.

The error output is

```
[nodemon] 2.0.7
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
[nodemon] watching extensions: js,json
[nodemon] starting `babel-node index.js`
'babel-node' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

my package.json scripts are

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "startdev": "nodemon --ext js,json  --exec babel-node index.js",
    "start": "babel-node index.js"
  }
```

and my dependencies and dev dependencies are

```
"dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "express-graphql": "^0.12.0",
    "graphql": "^15.4.0",
    "uuid": "^8.3.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.12.10",
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.10",
    "@babel/node": "^7.12.10",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread": "^7.12.1",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.12.11",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.7"
  }
```

I tried testing it without nodemon, by using the regular node command and it runs as expected

```
$ npm run start

> dev_forum@1.0.0 start
> babel-node index.js

Server is up...
```

My folder strucher is below

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5wHyS.png)

the contents of index.js are

```
const express = require("express");


const app = express();

app.listen(() => {
    console.log("Server is up...")
})
```

I have also tried deleting my node_modules and package-lock.json files and reinstalling but still crashes.

Answer (score 6):

Remove your node_modules and follow these steps:

```
 npm install --save-dev @babel/core @babel/cli @babel/preset-env @babel/node
```

Then, check the existence of these files:

node_modules/.bin/babel-node

node_modules/.bin/babel-node.cmd - windows only

node_modules/@babel/node/bin/babel-node.js

If everything looks good add to package.json:

```
"start": "nodemon --exec babel-node index.js",
```

Comment: I have done that but the error still persists... Error: Requires Babel "^7.0.0-0", but was loaded with "6.26.3".. so i solved it by reverting back to babel version 6 ... "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-node": "^0.0.1-security",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.7"
  }

Comment: Still the same issue? Try reverting your nide version to 14 or try to install nvm and check if the issue is not specific to node version.

Comment: Previously i was using node v15 but used node 14.15.4 and i still get the same error.. But i have found that the problem was with my babel plugin and presets.. i was using the @babel/preset-env and @babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread.. i tested each independently but still got the same error. i solved it by using the previous versions babel-preset-env and babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread package. These work with both babel v6 and v7

Comment: Thats great! Yes, It looks like the version issues only as installation seems fine, but good to hear that you resolved it.

Comment: It didn't work for me when I used "npm start", but it is fine when I use "yarn start"

Answer (score 3):

I ran into the same problem and solved it this way:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "babel-node src/index.js",
    "dev"  : "nodemon --exec npm start"
  }
```

In the terminal run

```
npm run dev
```

Answer (score 1):

None of the steps above work for me. I resorted to using yarn instead.
Delete your package-lock.json
Then do: yarn
This will add the dependencies, then you can run it, most likely with yarn run dev
(of course this depends on your scripts on package.json).