# I wants to run babel with nodemon but getting error ` code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',`

Tags: node.js

Both the modules are installed still it's showing errors in Windows 10

`[nodemon] 2.0.12`

`[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter` rs

`[nodemon] watching path(s): *.*`

`[nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json`

`[nodemon] starting` babel-node ./index.js

`node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:936`

throw err;

^

`Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Windows\System32\node_modules\babel-cli\bin\babel-node.js'`

```
`at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15) `
```

`at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)`

`at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:79:12)`

```
`at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 { `
```

`code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',`

`requireStack: []`

`}`

`[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...`

Comment: This is generally occurs when you have version mismatch which version are you running of node?

Comment: Also, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65827453/nodemon-babel-node-not-recognized-as-internal-or-external-command/65827691#65827691) link if this might help.

Comment: I'm using the node 16

Comment: It seems babel is not installed correctly, you might need to reinstall it with different versions. Try installing nvm and then make install of diff babel version. I have shared the link check it.