# Getting error "babel" is not recognized as an internal or external command,

Tags: javascript, babeljs, node-modules

I have a simple tests.js file that I wish to follow up with a source map file. I have tried initiating the dependencies yet the prompt shows the error. If anyone could specify the problem and the solution would be grateful ^^

**tests.js**

```
var add = (...arr) => {
    return arr.reduce((sum, el) =>{
        return sum+el;
    }, 0)
}
console.log(add(1,2,3));
```

I've tried these commands at first

`npm install -g babel-cli`

`npm install babel-preset-es2015`

`babel tests.js --out-file tests.dist.js --source-maps --presets=es2015`

But received the same error. I have followed another solution from the community but it still didn't work. The solution was to remove node_modules and reinitiate the dependencies.

`npm install --save-dev @babel/core @babel/cli @babel/preset-env @babel/node`

and add `"start": "nodemon --exec babel-node index.js",` in the dependencies.
I checked the node_modules and it had the existence of these files too.

node_modules/.bin/babel-node

node_modules/.bin/babel-node.cmd - windows only

node_modules/@babel/node/bin/babel-node.js

[The solution I followed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65827691/15752791) Still, I couldn't figure out how to solve this issue. This is my first time working with node and babel. My node version is `v16.13.1`

**Edited**

**Folder Structure**

```
Y:.
|   index.html
|   package-lock.json
|   package.json
|   tests.js
|   tree.txt
|   
\---node_modules
    |   .package-lock.json
    |   
    +---.bin
    |       babel
.....
```

It's huge!

**package.json**

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.16.8",
    "@babel/core": "^7.16.12",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.16.11"
  }
}
```

**.babelrc**

```
{
    "presents": [
        "@babel/preset-env"
    ]
}
```

**./node_modules/@babel/cli/bin/babel.js**

```
require("../lib/babel");
```

**After using bash for the command -**

`./node_modules/@babel/cli/bin/babel.js example.js --out-file main.dist.js`

**The error**

```
Error: Unknown option: .presents. Check out https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-core/#options for more information about options.
    at throwUnknownError (Y:\babel work\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\validation\options.js:133:27)
    at Y:\babel work\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\validation\options.js:118:5
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at validateNested (Y:\babel work\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\validation\options.js:94:21)
    at validate (Y:\babel work\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\validation\options.js:85:10)
    at Y:\babel work\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\config-chain.js:209:34
    at cachedFunction (Y:\babel work\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\caching.js:60:27)
    at cachedFunction.next (<anonymous>)
    at evaluateSync (Y:\babel work\node_modules\gensync\index.js:251:28)
    at sync (Y:\babel work\node_modules\gensync\index.js:89:14) {
  code: 'BABEL_UNKNOWN_OPTION'
}
```

Comment: did you set `.babelrc` file with some configuration like this `{
    "presets": [
        "@babel/preset-env"
    ]
}`

Comment: Can you share your folder structure?

Comment: @cooskun Hi, I have added some portion of the folder structure. It has `.bin` and `@babel` and a lot of stuff in node_modules.

Comment: @ullaskunder Hi, I tried the solution you posted. added the `.babelrc` file but whenever I go for `/babel.js --version` it shows `require("../lib/babel");` in the `babel.js` file. How to go forth?

Comment: if you installed `@babel/cli`, `@babel/core` globally then no need to use `/` just check `babel --version` , if you install locally like my example then the babel path will be `./node_modules/@babel/cli/bin/babel.js` `! I am using bash`

Comment: @ullaskunder Hey, I am using the bash, and `./node_modules/@babel/cli/bin/babel.js  --version` works fine. But next command `./node_modules/@babel/cli/bin/babel.js example.js --out-file main.dist.js` shows this error. ` I am adding the error in the post.

Comment: okk. I have file called `example.js` but you have `test.js` as I can see.
babel command take example.js(your code) and transpile it or `--out-file` as main.dist.js(create by babel any name you want)

Comment: @ullaskunder Thank you, so much! I sorted all the issues now Thanks to you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hyy,
[update]

installing babel locally

- `npm i @babel/core @babel/cli @babel/preset-env`
- Inside package.json add `npm` script

```json
  "scripts": {
    "start-babel": "babel example.js --out-file main.dist.js"
  },
```

- You need `.babelrc` file for all you configuration

```js
// basic need
{
    "presets": [
        "@babel/preset-env"
    ]
}
```

- Run script by `npm run start-babel` this will create `main.dist.js` js transpiled file

---

- You need `.babelrc` file with some configuration
- if you have installed `@bable/core @babel/cli @bable/preset-env` locally

  - Then you have to use the path of of babel.js of node_modules like this

[image]

- if you installed it globally using -g then you don't need a path just use `babel`